# SOAP Server always returns "rpc:ProcedureNotPresentProcedure not present"

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl, soap

I'm setting up a Soap service using PHP's SoapServer. No matter what I do I get "rpc:ProcedureNotPresentProcedure not present."

I'm using curl to post to it. It looks like this.

```
$payload = $data['xml'];
try {
   $soap = curl_init('http://localhost/Connector/index.php');
   curl_setopt_array($soap, array (
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
      CURLOPT_POST => TRUE
   ));

   curl_setopt_array($soap, array (
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
         'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
         'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload)
       )
   ));
   $response = curl_exec($soap);
```

The $payload variable contains the xml that looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Envelope xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns3="http://localhost/Connector/">
    <ns2:Body>
        <ns3:addNewAccount>
            <systemData>
                <id>QWQ</id>
            </systemData>
            <customerData>
                <id>666</id>
                <name>ACME UNLIMITED</name>
                <billCycleDay>1</billCycleDay>
            </customerData>
        </ns3:addNewAccount>
    </ns2:Body>
</ns2:Envelope>
```

My Soap Server looks like this.

```
<?php
$soapoptions = array (
    'classmap' => ConnectorService::$classmap,
);

    $soapoptions['cache_wsdl'] = WSDL_CACHE_NONE;
    $soapoptions['trace'] = TRUE;

file_put_contents('/tmp/debug', print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE), FILE_APPEND);
$connectorService = new \SoapServer("/ConnectorService/wsdl/connector.wsdl", $soapoptions);
$connectorService->setClass("ConnectorService");
file_put_contents('/tmp/debug', print_r($connectorService->getFunctions(), TRUE), FILE_APPEND);
$connectorService->handle();
```

I'm getting the xml in the request, it gets written to the /tmp/debug file, as does the functions available (addNewAccount).

The ConnectorService class looks like this.

```
class ConnectorService implements AccountInterface
{
    public static $classmap = array(
        'addNewAccount'=>'addNewAccount'
    );

    public function addNewAccount($mixed = NULL)
    {
        $args = func_get_args();

        $response = new AccountResponse();

        $handler = new AddNewAccountHandler();
        $result = $handler->process($args[0]);

        // return the result
        return $result->getSoapVar();
    }
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting "rpc:ProcedureNotPresentProcedure not present."

**UPDATE**
If I don't rely on php://input to provide the xml to the SoapServer, but rather I load xml from the filesystem and pass it to the SoapServer->handle() method, I'm getting it to work.

If I dump the contents of php://input, it does have the xml in it. So why doesn't SoapServer pick it up. As I understand it, if you don't provide a parameter to SoapServer->handle() it supposed to check php://input for the xml.

**What would cause php://input to not work or for SoapServer to not be reading it?**

Comment: Oddly enough, I ran into this same error, but this time it was a namespace issue. http://webdeveloper.gdemolished.com/soap-request-generates-500-with-nothing-in-the-apache-or-php-log/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I've got a new development stack setup on VirtualBox with Ubuntu 14.04 and I didn't have the php-soap package installed. I don't know what this package provides, without it I was able to instantiate SoapServer and SoapClient and I was able to make calls to methods in my wsdl, but it didn't read php://input when I wanted to just throw xml at the Soap server.

So I installed php-soap
apt-get install php-soap

It installed php-auth-sasl php-http-request php-mail php-mail-mime php-net-dime php-net-smtp php-net-socket php-net-url php-soap

I think that php-http-request is probably the one that I really needed. But either way, that's what you need to do if you run into this goofy problem. Total durp problem that I spent way too much time noodling around with.